# Random space at the end of printed outputs

Tags: python

My code says its missing a new line after it is submitted

Here is my code

```
import math
r = math.pow(2,1/12)

f0 = float(input(''))
print('{:.2f}'.format(f0), end = " ")

for n in range(1,5):
    
    fn = f0 * math.pow(r,n)
    
    print('{:.2f}'.format(fn), end = ' ')
print ()
```

It is [showing that there is an extra space at the end.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ8dy.png)

Comment: submitted. Where.

Comment: you have `end= " "` that means it will put an `' '` at the end ... why are you curious about there being one?

Comment: I need to remove it so it will mark it as correct.

Comment: As I understand author want remove last space from: print('{:.2f}'.format(fn), end = ' ').  author shows this at the attached picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ8dy.png

Comment: so `print( *('{:.2f}'.format(f0**n) for n in range(0,5))` - this will only have spaces in between and print all the numbers in one line...

Comment: **Patrick Artner**, your are absolute right! but I think author is getting started with python and your method is difficult to understand, but more elegance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*this one :*

```
import math
r = math.pow(2,1/12)

f0 = float(input(''))
print('{:.2f}'.format(f0), end='') # < remove space

for n in range(1,5):
    
    fn = f0 * math.pow(r,n)
    
    print(' ',end='') # < put space there

    print('{:.2f}'.format(fn), end='')

print ()
```

outs:

```
% python3 1.py
10
10.00 10.59 11.22 11.89 12.60
```

there are no space after *12.60*